# How to add value for empty cells in Ag grid Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using ag grid to show data to end users my aim is to add N/A for cells which are empty could any please tell me how can I do this. I have created a demo under this link "https://plnkr.co/edit/wtDE6ZSznlUXRlt0?preview"

My grid is like this
[image]

and I want to add N/A for empty cells and my final grid will look like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding a cell renderer into the `columnDefs` might work:

```
headerName: 'Value',
field: 'entityFamily',
flex: 1,
cellRenderer: params => params.value === "" ? "N/A" : params.value,
```

[example of cell renderer in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tr23.jpg)

`CellRender` documentation is here:

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/component-cell-renderer/